# 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'id' error on Facebook c# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using facebook c# SDK (i think v4) for my canvas app.

For the last 2 days I'm getting this kind of error when tring to access my facebook canvas app.

This error is not permanant and apear only for some of the users.

Here is the log:

MESSAGE: **'bool' does not contain a definition for 'id'**

SOURCE: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly

QUERYSTRING: fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=3_0

FORM: signed_request=PiF_P1VgfghdfWryycfyS-OFaZOTsNB_rP7up2OsTQ.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0ifhfhfghjhgNiIsImV4cGlyZXMiOjEzMzQ3NDMyMDAsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTMzNDczOTM5NSwib2F1dGhfdG9rZW4iOiJBQUFDUDZGertyertyING9aQ0YyQWNhNEVaQUtLMVZkVGIzOWVNTTZaQkFaQmJ2Q3oyMVMwNXFmV0R6SmlkQjNsRXgwWkFjMHpKUDJ6QlZoWTZ4am1RNUlpSUFmbzZNQnlXN3kxQnVhhpNRVBiV4ggY7IiwidXNlciI6eyJjbdghdfghdfaWwiLCJsb2NhbGUiOiJoZV9JTCIsImFnZSI6eyJtaW4iOjIxfX0sInVzZXJfaWQiOiIxMyumhjmhgjMzQzNjI3ODYifQ

TARGETSITE: System.Object CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.Object)

STACKTRACE: at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0) at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) at en_bubbles_Default.ShowFacebookContent() in c:\hshome\Default.aspx.cs:line 93 at en_bubbles_Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\hshome\Default.aspx.cs:line 29

And here is the code:
    var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
    var app = new FacebookOAuthClient(FacebookApplication.Current);

```
dynamic ac = app.GetApplicationAccessToken();

string accessToken = fb.AccessToken.ToString();

dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("me");

Session["fbid"] = myInfo["id"];
```

The error is in the last line

Can some one tell my what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The call to Get("me") is not returning the expected object which has the property "id" instead the myInfo dynamic object is just a bool type. And bool can only be true or false. Have you identified under what circumstances you see this. I suspect it would be intermittent. Perhaps you should just check if myInfo is bool and abort or retry the operation if it is.